# Why does this NetTrain example fail?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have some training data of the form `{{x, y}, bool}`, e.g.

```
trainingdata = {{{0.655577, -0.11215}, 0}, {{0.091856, -0.784234}, 0}, {{0.988837, 0.703962}, 1},  ... etc }
```

Now I build a simple neural network.

```
layer1 = LinearLayer[3, "Input" -> 2];
layer2 = LinearLayer[4, "Input" -> 3];
layer3 = LinearLayer[1, "Input" -> 4];
chain = NetChain[{layer1, layer2, layer3}]
```

and then

```
trained = NetTrain[chain, #[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ trainingData]
```

but this results in `$Failed`.

On the other hand, the following works fine:

```
otherchain = NetChain[{2, 3, 4, 1}];
trained = NetTrain[otherchain, #[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ trainingData]
```

The difference between the objects seems to be that `chain` takes as input a vector of size 2 and `otherchain` takes as an input a tensor, which is then fed to a `LinearLayer` of size 2. I can't find anything in the `NetTrain` or `NetChain` documentation which addresses this difference.

I've tried building a training net for `chain` from scratch like is described on [this page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksIntroduction.html#621730217) but it also fails, which I anticipate is for the same reason as above.

Comment: You're correct that the issue is the Input to the network. If you remove the "Input" specifiers in the layers the net works correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you need to specify the "Output" type of the `NetChain`.

```
layer1 = LinearLayer[3, "Input" -> 2];
layer2 = LinearLayer[4, "Input" -> 3];
layer3 = LinearLayer[1, "Input" -> 4];
chain = NetChain[{layer1, layer2, layer3}, "Output" -> "Scalar"]
```

Appears to work correctly. Unfortunately I don't know why that is in this case.

Just a note - often, you can get away without specifying Input/Output between layers.